# Why is my map visual not working on Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

My bubble map is giving an error, it does not load.(After my PC restarts for updates.)
This has happened before, when creating other dashboards also if a map was inserted, after I closed and reopened Power Bi.
I've tried searching in other places, and it says to go to https://app.powerbi.com/admin-portal/, but it is BLANK.
I tried to enable some map-related functions within Power BI, but also without success.
The issue is that in addition to giving an error, Power BI also does NOT allow me to reconstruct this visual map on the same dashboard.
Has anyone ever experienced this?
 [Here is the link to the IMAGE of my error! The error message is in Portuguese and it says to check the Admin Portal on https://app.powerbi.com/admin-portal/ , but when i do it, all I find is a blank section instead.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXhRY.png)

Thanks.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting, as was suggested when you created your account.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.